# How do I view my django site from other devices which are connected to the same network

Tags: python, django

I wanted to view my django site from another device. I ran this command

```
py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888
```

Then I went to my phone web browser and entered this url

**(Network ip address):8888**

It was searching for that url and a little while later the connection timed out. What do I do

Comment: Check the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get you device IP address by running command

```
ipconfig
```

then use your device IP with django command to run the project

```
python manage.py runserver device_IP:port_number
```

for example,

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.111.111:8888
```

Now you can access the django site from other devices in your network by running `192.168.111.111:8888`